# WPF / DeferRefresh with bound listbox

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox, refresh

I am trying to push in a number of updates to a collection to which I have bound a list box. Since the list can get quite big, i am trying to turn off updates (sorting, etc) until I finished inserting all the new items.

I figured:

```
using (col.DeferRefesh())
{
   .. add the items
}
```

but this raises an exception saying that I cannot add/remove items while DeferRefresh() is on.
Is there a proper pattern for doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Adding or Removing items from a CollectionView would cause an `InvalidOperationException` as the operations set `IsAddingNew` or `IsEditingItem` flags to true for the CollectionView.

What you're allowed to do in DeferRefresh() is to change the sort descriptions.

[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/08/28/collectionview-deferrefresh-my-new-best-friend.aspx) gives an idea about where DeferRefresh() comes to use. Also, it's pretty much contradictory to defer collection view refresh when you're actually changing values in a collectionview.

Comment: There are situations where you would want to suspend updates to the collection and collectionview while you make a bunch of changes

Comment: pickles - I totally agree! So those changes would be done at the UI level and not the code level. Once we exit the using block. EndDefer() is called automatically to commit those changes that you've made. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to implement/derive your own collection and implement a defer refresh functionality at the collection level and then fire a collection changed event with reset as the change type when defer refresh completes